# "pygmentize: command not found" Even though I already installed pygments on my system

Tags: python, latex, pygments, pygmentize

I tried installing [pygments](https://pygments.org/) on **Debian 9** using both `apt-get install python3-pygments` and `pip install Pygments` but no method makes it work on the command line.

My suspicion is that my *PATH* doesn't contain the path of the installations. I added */usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/* to my *PATH* since the pygments package is installed there but of course this is not a solution since there's not a single bin or executable there. There are scripts there but none with the 'x' permission.

What dir should I add to my *PATH* variable then? `apt-file list python3-pygments` only shows the previously added dir (*/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*).

Maybe the problem is unrelated to my *PATH*. I don't know. But I need to make this work in order to use the **minted** latex package.
There's this quote on the pygments [website](https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) which makes me think I need to install something else:

> You can use Pygments from the shell, provided you installed the pygmentize script.

I wish they could write more about how to install said script since I can't find anything on their website or the internet. For what I see online, most people just install pygments normally and then they are able to use minted so I'm skeptical of this "script".

Comment: I have this same question!  I've wasted so much time trying to use minted.  Where in the world is pygmentize???  Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yeah. Try installing from source. The version the repos have for Debian 9 is very old. https://github.com/pygments/pygments

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found it!  I uninstalled and re-installed and this time I got the useful warning:

```
Installing collected packages: Pygments
  WARNING: The script pygmentize.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\CarmanBr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Updated my path and now it's finally working!